# Excess space - figures on the bottom of page

Tags: spacing

So there are a few other questions with the same problem but I tried every single solution (that I could understand) and the problem persists. It seems like LaTeX wants to place my figures at the bottom of pages instead of immediately after the text.
So far I only managed to delete the space between the text and the figure by adding % but that created a space between the header and the text. And adding % after the header doesn't work. Please help. I already tried using float with figure placement options and none of them did anything.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\subsection{Determination of saliva concentration}

Using a BCA test, the protein concentration of unstimulated saliva was assessed. The results showed saliva protein concentrations of 1.2 - 1.4mg/ml.\\\\%
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/bcasaliva1.png}
\captionof{figure}[Determination of saliva protein concentration]{Determination of saliva protein concentration via a BCA assay}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: I think `\begin{center}` should be placed before `\includegraphics`, not before `\subsection`.

Comment: The problem is that you only have two boxes on the page: the subsection title and the figures.  LaTeX spaces them out so that you don't have blank space between the figures and the page number.  You can add more stuff to the page, or you can use `\raggedbottom`.  But it's not clear what you want to have happen.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me (with a warning about the unknown `.png` file).

```
% figprob.tex

\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\subsection{Determination of saliva concentration}

Using a BCA test, the protein concentration of unstimulated saliva was assessed. The results showed saliva protein concentrations of 1.2 - 1.4mg/ml. % \\\\%
\includegraphics[scale=0.6]{figures/bcasaliva1.png}
\captionof{figure}[Determination of saliva protein concentration]{Determination of saliva protein concentration via a BCA assay}

\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think `\begin{center}` should be placed before `\includegraphics`, not before `\subsection`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Maybe it should but that is where the questioner put it. I think that your comment is better attached to the question rather than the answer. or put as a new answer.

Comment: I have written my comment also to the question. However, I think an answer should be correct because other users can see it and think it is correct.

Comment: @CarLaTeX I believe that my answer to the question as asked is correct.  What makes you think that the questioner wanted something other than a bunch of centered stuff?  If so that is the subject of another question. --- GOM